# Notify me when I am using if expression, that can be simplified

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jslint

I am using JsLint with Grunt to do basic validation of my JavaScript. It does a pretty good job and allows me to eliminate some of the potential bugs and make my code better/cleaner.

Recently I found that sometimes I am using something like:

```
if(myRandomExpression){
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Which can be simplified to `return myRandomExpression;`. It is not a single time problem, I am doing this a lot. Clearly I would like to avoid such things in the future and write it in a simpler (second) way.

After looking at jslint options, I have found nothing that looks similar. Is there a way for me to be notified when I am using If expressions that can be simplified?

**P.S.** I know that I can go through all if statements and review them (also some IDE shows this problem when you next to it), but this is not the kind of solution I want.

Comment: In case you can't find anything better, it seems that [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) [plans to implement this validation](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/667) (point 37: Redundant if statement)